# Como usar gtkmm-3 e entrada padrão juntos?

Tags: c++, linux, gtk

Quero fazer um programa com Gtk que leia dados da entrada padrão e interprete fazendo desenhos em uma `DrawingArea`.

O conceito é simples, mas me deparei com um problema: depois que eu chamo `Gtk::Application::run` o único código escrito por mim a executar é o sinal `on_draw` da `DrawingArea`.

Preciso receber a entrada padrão e não posso fazê-lo no método `on_draw` pois o programa pararia de responder.

O que eu quero é poder enviar dados a qualquer hora, e que o desenho atualize em tempo real.

A entrada, interpretação e a exibição do desenho na tela são fáceis de implementar, mas fazê-los juntos parece uma tarefa difícil.

E aí como eu poderia fazê-lo? Um exemplo bem simples seria bem útil *(basicamente o que eu quero é conseguir entrar texto enquanto a função `Gtk::Application::run` executa)*

Answer (score 2):

Nunca usei gtkmm, porém, em gtk "standard" eu vejo duas formas de fazer isso (em linux)...

1. A forma mais simples: Levantar uma thread lendo a entrada padrão com fgets e incluindo os dados numa GAsyncQueue lida por um timer na thread principal. A fila é para evitar que a thread acesse a fila de mensagens da gui em um momento "indevido".
2. Mais complicado: "encapsular" o handle da entrada padrão num GIO (via g_unix_input_stream) e tratar como qualquer outra fonte de dados. Esse só usa uma thread e evita eventuais problemas de sincronização; é o que geralmente uso.

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução para seu problema é utilizar comunicação entre processos ([IPC](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comunica%C3%A7%C3%A3o_entre_processos)). Dessa forma, você divide seu programa em duas partes:

- A primeira irá iniciar o outro processo (programa) que fará os desenhos e em seguida funciona apenas para receber os valores de entrada do usuário.
- A segunda parte "ouvirá" os comandos enviados pelo primeiro processo e fará os desenhos.

Para fazer isso, você pode usar o próprio `gtkmm-3` ([exemplo](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/3.3/sec-plugs-sockets-example.html.zh_CN)) ou outra biblioteca que faça o servido. Por exemplo: [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess.html).